# How to initialize char* args[] without getting a compiler warning

Tags: c++

Compiler is complaining on the following line.

```
char* args[] = {"/bin/bla.py", "-h"};
```

**The error is:**

```
deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

I am compiling with `-Werror=write-strings` so I know how to stop getting this error; 
but I am looking to see what am I doing wrong and how I can prevent the warning?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to `char const *args[]`.  If you do not intend to change which strings are in this table, then use

```
char const *const args[] = { ....
```

The `write-strings` error means to give an error for your code. Your code is legal  but bad practice. It's bad practice because string literals contain `const char`s , so it would be undefined behaviour to write to them. Making the pointer point to `const char`s means you get a compiler message if you try to write to them.